# Automation of debugging process in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Basically I want to automate the debugging process. Lets suppose I have a program it is reading some files, I want to write a code that will automatically called when the program could not open the file. In that code, I want to get the whole data of stack trace of the occured exception. Can I do that? If yes, then tell me how? If not then suggest any alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Win32 API for capturing stack traces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), of course,  but they're unpleasant to use and are probably an overkill for a single debugging mission.   What you probably want is to set a tracepoint at file read failure(check 'When hit..' on a breakpoint), and type $CALLSTACK at the 'Print a message' edit box.